# How to access object called _ (underscore) into a variable

Tags: php

I have the following object. How can I get the value of GrossAmount (1.10) in this case as a variable?

I have tried:

```
$gross = $object->GrossAmount->_;
```

Whereas `$id = $object->GrossAmount->currencyID;`

Does give me the current code of GBP

But this isn't working.

```
Array
(
    [TransactionID] => 9BBXH1113VA716445A
    [ParentTransactionID] => 
    [ReceiptID] => 
    [TransactionType] => express-checkout
    [PaymentType] => instant
    [PaymentDate] => 2013-02-28T18:26:43Z
    [GrossAmount] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_] => 1.10
            [currencyID] => GBP
        )

    [FeeAmount] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_] => 0.21
            [currencyID] => GBP
        )

    [TaxAmount] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_] => 0.00
            [currencyID] => GBP
        )

    [ExchangeRate] => 
    [PaymentStatus] => Completed
    [PendingReason] => none
    [ReasonCode] => none
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm your top-level object is an array, not an object. So you should use `$object['GrossAmount']->_` to access that field.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
$object->GrossAmount->{'_'}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try with

```
$gross = $object->GrossAmount->{"_"};
```

Comment: At least according to a quick test on the interactive PHP shell `_` works fine as a regular attribute.

Comment: I guess I was thinking that an underscore wasn't allowed in variable naming.